# Counting columns in a csv file IF column contains a 1. (only 1's and 0's in csv file) Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to loop through a csv file of ones and zeroes, in Python.  If the column has a 1 in it then I count that column and add to the counter.  I expect
a count of 3 but I'm getting 18.  I can achieve correct answer when I need to count rows with ones in them but stuck with columns. Any pointers appreciated, here is what I have:

```
  #  section 2 feature 3.
  with open(file_path) as csv_file_to_read:
  width_in = csv.reader(csv_file_to_read, delimiter=',')
  count_col = 0
  for row in width_in:
      for column in row:
          if '1' in column:
              count_col += 1
  print(count_col, ' f3')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Fire up a debugger and step through the code, or add some strategically placed print statements to check your assumptions (csv parsing, content of a cell, ...).

Comment: Can you show us the data?

Comment: Your code will count the total number of 1s in the data. If you want to count the number of columns which contain a 1, you'll need to handle columns with 1s in multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
count_col = 0
for i in df.columns:
    if any(df[i].isin([1])):
        count_col += 1
print(count_col)
```

Hope this helps. Since, you have not shown the data, it is based on the assumption.

Comment: Thank you Srce Cde.  Perfect.  Gave me the value I was looking for.  Have not used pandas before.